# Teaching the type checker that 2 ^ e ≢ 0

Tags: agda

Suppose that I have shown that `2 ^ e ≢ 0` for all `e`:

```
module Question where

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.DivMod
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate 2^e≢0 : (e : ℕ) → 2 ^ e ≢ 0
```

I would now like the type checker to use this knowledge in situations like the following:

```
postulate lemma : (m e : ℕ) → m / 2 ^ e ≤ m
```

Here the type checker complains about the `2 ^ e` divisor with an error message of `_≢0_6 : Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.False ((2 ^ e) ≟ 0)`:

Is there a way to make the decision procedure `≟` use my `2^e≢0` lemma?

I could come up with the following workaround, which seems a little clumsy. My idea was to use an obviously non-zero divisor `suc x` and a proof that it is equal to `2 ^ e`:

```
postulate lemma′ : (m e x : ℕ) → suc x ≡ 2 ^ e → m / suc x ≤ m
```

Analogously, I could use Agda's `div-helper` built-in instead of `/` and pass `x` to it instead of `suc x`.

But I was wondering, whether I could teach the type checker new tricks instead of using a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the dividend and the divisor, `_/_` takes an implicit parameter which is the proof that the divisor is not equal to 0.

As explained in the file `divmod.agda` the reason for this parameter to be implicit is that it can be inferred when the divisor is of the form `suc n` For instance, the following definition typechecks correctly because `2` is definitionally equal to `suc 1`:

```
four : ℕ
four = 8 / 2
```

However, for a given `n`, `m / n` does not typeckeck directly because the proof cannot be inferred in the general case. When it cannot, it needs to be passed directly as an instantiation of the additional implicit parameter.

In your case, your divisor is propositionally not equal to 0, but not definitionally which means you have to go through this process, as follows:

```
postulate lemma : ∀ {m e} → (m / 2 ^ e) {fromWitnessFalse (2^e≢0 {e})} ≤ m
```

In order to be able to use `fromWitnessFalse` you need to add the following import to your file:

```
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation! In addition to answering my question, it inspired me to go and explore `toWitness` / `fromWitness` a little more.